# 背景にCSSのfilterを使用すると，前面の文字が表示されない

Tags: html, css

背景要素に`filter: brightness`を使い，明度を暗くした後，その前面に白い文字を表示したいと思っています．

```css
#background {
  z-index: -1000;
  
  height: 300px;
  width:  100%;
  
  background-color: #555;

  filter: brightness(20%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(20%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(20%);
  -o-filter: brightness(20%);
}

#content {
  z-index: 1000;
  
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  
  margin-top: -300px;
  color: #FFF;
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h1>
  テスト
  </h1>
</div>
```

firefoxでは正常に表示できるのですが，Safari，Chrome等Webkit系では文字が表示されていないようです．
また，`-webkit-filter: brightness`を削除することで文字は表示されるようになるのですが，今度はfilterが効きません．

本番環境では，背景として画像を使用したいと思っているため，できれば`filter: brightness`を使って明度を下げたいと考えています．

何か良い解決策はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`z-index` を指定する際には `position` に static 以外を指定する必要がありますが、あなたのコードでは `#background` `#content` のどちらにもこれが指定されていません。

これがなくても動くのは Firefox のバグのような気がします。

---

以下解説。

画像編集ソフトでいうところのレイヤーのように、Webページのレンダリングには**スタックコンテキスト**という概念があり、これは `opacity` `transform` などを指定した際や、 `position` と `z-index` を組み合わせた場合に作成されます。

- [要素の重なりについて本気出して考えてみた（z-indexとか何とかとか） – No.1026](http://no1026.com/archives/104)
- [スタック文脈 - Web developer guide | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

描画順をざっくり書くと、次のようになります。（今回関係するもののみ）

- `z-index` がマイナスのスタックコンテキスト
- スタックコンテキストを作らない要素
- `z-index` が `auto` や 0 のスタックコンテキスト
  （`position` + `z-index` 以外で作られたスタックコンテキストもここ）
- `z-index` が 1 以上のスタックコンテキスト

例:

```css
body { background: #fdd; }

.z-1 { z-index: -1; background: #efe; }
.za { z-index: auto; background: #ada; }
.z0 { z-index: 0; background: #5b5; }
.z1 { z-index: 1; background: #090; }

.c div { height: 40px; }
.c :nth-child(2) { margin-top: -30px; margin-left: 100px; }
.c :nth-child(3) { margin-top: -30px; margin-left: 200px; }
.c :nth-child(4) { margin-top: -30px; margin-left: 300px; }

.with-pos div { position: relative; }
```

```html
<h2>position: static （デフォルト値）</h2>

<div class="c">
  <div class="z-1">z-index: -1</div>
  <div class="za">z-index: auto</div>
  <div class="z0">z-index: 0</div>
  <div class="z1">z-index: 1</div>
</div>
<div class="c">
  <div class="z1">z-index: 1</div>
  <div class="z0">z-index: 0</div>
  <div class="za">z-index: auto</div>
  <div class="z-1">z-index: -1</div>
</div>

<h2>position: relative</h2>

<div class="c with-pos">
  <div class="z-1">z-index: -1</div>
  <div class="za">z-index: auto</div>
  <div class="z0">z-index: 0</div>
  <div class="z1">z-index: 1</div>
</div>
<div class="c with-pos">
  <div class="z1">z-index: 1</div>
  <div class="z0">z-index: 0</div>
  <div class="za">z-index: auto</div>
  <div class="z-1">z-index: -1</div>
</div>
```

それを踏まえて、今回のケースを考えてみます。

まず、 [`filter` を指定した段階](http://jsfiddle.net/fq7o70uf/1/)ではネガティブマージンで引き込んだ `#content` が見えなくなっています。これは `#background` にスタックコンテキストが生成されたことにより、スタックコンテキストを持たない `#content` より上に描画されるためです。

> A computed value of other than none results in the creation of a stacking context the same way that CSS opacity does.
>   <sub>--- https://drafts.fxtf.org/filters/#FilterProperty より引用</sub>

そして順番を指定しようと `z-index` を指定されたようですが、static 以外の `position` が指定されていない、つまり位置指定されていないので、本来効果はありません。これは `filter` がスタックコンテキストを生成していても同じです。

> **位置指定されたボックスでは**、z-index プロパティは次の定義を行います:
>
> 1. 現在のスタック文脈における、ボックスのスタックレベル
> 2. ボックスがローカルなスタック文脈を作るかどうか
>
> <sub>--- https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/z-index より引用。強調は私によるものです。</sub>

例えば、先ほど引用した個所でも例示されていた `opacity` の場合、Firefox でも Chrome でも `z-index` は無視されています。

```css
#background {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* ↑を足すとz-index通り下に潜る */
  
  z-index: -1000;
  
  height: 300px;
  width:  100%;
  
  background-color: #555;

  opacity: 0.99;
}

#content {  
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -300px;
  
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h1>
  テスト
  </h1>
</div>
```

にもかかわらず、Firefox では `filter` を指定しただけで `z-index` が機能していますね。

また、前述の描画順を考えると、

- `#background` の z-index をマイナスにする
- `#content` の z-index を 1 以上にする

のどちらかで十分とも言えます。（もちろん `position` は必要です）

Comment: 結果として、#contentにposition: relativeを設定、かつ、z-index: 1とすることで期待通りの表示となりました。ありがとうございます。 http://jsfiddle.net/u1dxysk1/